# select multiple columns using linq and sum them up

Tags: c#, database, linq, select, sum

How can i select multiple columns and calculate the total amount.

For example, in my database i got a few fields which are named:

5hunderedBills,
2hunderedBills,
1hunderedBills,
etc.

And the value of those fields are for example:

5,
2,
3

And the sum would be:

5hunderedBills * 5 + 2hunderedBills * 2 + 1hunderedBills * 3

How can i do that with LINQ in one select statement?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will sum up all three of those columns with weights and return the total sum for all rows.

```
YourDatabaseContext.Where( item => item.Date == someCriteria).Sum( item => item.FiveHundredBills * 5 + item.TwoHundredBills * 2 + item.OneHundredBills );
```

If you need a list of a sum for each row, swap methods `Sum()` and `Select()`:

```
YourDatabaseContext.Where( item => item.Date == someCriteria).Select( item => item.FiveHundredBills * 5 + item.TwoHundredBills * 2 + item.OneHundredBills );
```

Comment: Hi,

This works but i forgot to mention there should be a where clause to check for date. How can i implement the where clause? Thats all i need to know now. Thank you!

Comment: @Yustme, Added Where() clause to LINQ query. For the future, check this Web site for a good set of starting samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx and install LinqPad.

Comment: Hi, I already figured it out via codeproject.com That ms.com site with 101 examples, walked them 50 times already. I'll look into LinqPad. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = from b in db.bills
select b.5hunderedBills + b.2hunderedBills + b.1hunderedBills ;
```

`db` is the name of your LINQ DataContext and `bills` is the name of the table in question.